# DateTimePicker custom formatting not displaying

Tags: vb.net, winforms

This is a WinForms, VB.NET app, using VS 2010 Pro. I added a datetimepicker to a form. Set the custom property to MM/dd/yyy. the relevant part of my function is as below:

```
        If IsDate(_uni.unitRentDate) Then
            t_TenantUnitRentDate.Value = _uni.unitRentDate
        Else
            If Not _uni.unitRentDate.HasValue Then
                t_TenantUnitRentDate.Value = New DateTime(2010, 1, 1)
            End If

        End If
```

_uni is a table in the EF and unitRentDate is stored in that table as DATETIME. The datetimepicker is t_TenantUnitRentDate.

The problem I am having is that when the form loads the dateTimePicker is showing the date in the format of this example Saturday , September 10, 2012 . This is not what I am wanting it to do at all.. It should be showing as 9/10/2012 . Why is this failing I looked at the date being returned from the database and it is showing a correct date value at that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it again by setting Format property to 'Custom'

Comment: I dont know how I missed the format property in The properties for the datetimepicker. It was right under what I thought was causing the problem and was set to long so no matter what I did it would always display in the way that I didnt need it to. Thanks much

Answer (score 1):

Probably the custom format `MM/dd/yyy` is invalid. The year must have either two or four digits.

```
MM/dd/yy
```

or

```
MM/dd/yyyy
```

Comment: The MSDN says that the year format for custom formatting is either yy for 2 digit or yyy for 4 digit. I got that formatting off their information. Im guessing they did it like that to shorten it as I double checked it just because of that.